# Laravel Check if Array is empty

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am struggling with displaying some content depending on if an array property does have a value or not.
If an article has a title, I want to display the content of the entire article, if not I want to show something else. However, it doesn't work. The code in the else statement is not executed.

What's wrong here?

My Code is:

```
@foreach($restaurantmenue as $daily)
                    @foreach($daily->articles as $menue)
                     @if(!empty($menue->title))
                       <div class="card card-horizontal">
                         <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-5">
                             <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                               <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}" alt="..." style="display: none;">
                               <div class="filter filter-azure">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round">
                                     <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> SMÄCKT MIR
                                 </button>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="content">
                                  <p class="category text-info">
                                       <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Best of
                                   </p>

                                   <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                       <h4 class="title">{{$menue->title}} </h4>
                                   </a>
                                   <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                       <p class="description">{{$menue->body}}</p>
                                       <br />
                                       {{$menue->price}} €
                                   </a>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                       <div class="stats">
                                           <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                              <i class="fa fa-male"></i> {{$restaurant->name}}
                                           </a>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="stats">
                                         <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                           <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 23 Comments
                                         </a>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="stats">
                                          <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                           <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> 231 Likes
                                          </a>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                      @else
                        No Articles for Today
                     @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

Comment: put a print_r($menue) by replacing the line @if(!empty($menue->title)) and check the content.

Comment: This is the output: App\Article Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => body [2] => price [3] => facebook_page_id [4] ...

Comment: there might be something. try with `isset`

Comment: with isset there is the same relust as with !empty.  Can somebody explain why the obove is not working? Is it really that difficult ?

Comment: We don't know what are you storing in $menue, instead of print_r($menue) try print_r($menue->title) and tell us the content.

Comment: The output of print_r($menue->title) is 'tuesday'. it's just a string. So i just want to check if there is a value. If so i need to tisplay the entire article like in the code above. If no I just want to display "no article".

Answer (score 40):

If you are getting data using ORM in laravel like

```
$data = \App\Model::get();
```

then you can check whether the `$data` is empty or not as following :

```
@if(!$data->isEmpty())
     // $data is not empty
@else
    // $data is empty
@endif
```

**Reference** : [Check Here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty)

But if you use `find` or `findOrFail`, then you can check array as

```
$data = \App\Model::findOrFail($id);


@if(!empty($data))
     // $data is not empty
@else
    // $data is empty
@endif
```

Comment: I am using //Show Daily Dishes for current Profile
      $restaurantmenue = User::where('id', $id)->with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
      }])->get();

Comment: You can use `$restaurantmenue->isEmpty()`  to check whether array is empty or not

Comment: The code on the else statement is still not executed.

Comment: It's only executed if the data is empty. The logic is correct, maybe there's something else we are not seeing in your code?

Comment: Fantastic answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you.

```
$processes = [1, 2, 4, 5];
$maintenance = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$array_value = function ($value, $array) {
    $str = "$value";
    if (in_array($str, $array)) {
        echo 5;
    } else {
        echo 1;
    }
};

foreach ($maintenance as $m) {
    $array_value ($m, $processes);
}
```

Basically I'm comparing two arrays and display 5 if data found on the other array

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code is executed if the article is not empty. But The code in the else statement is still not executed. I still can't display the "no article" message it there are no articles available

```
  @if(!$restaurantmenue->isEmpty())
                    @foreach($restaurantmenue as $daily)
                        @foreach($daily->articles as $menue)

                           <div class="card card-horizontal">
                             <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                                   <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}" alt="..." style="display: none;">
                                   <div class="filter filter-azure">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round">
                                         <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> SMÄCKT MIR
                                     </button>
                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <p class="category text-info">
                                           <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Best of
                                       </p>

                                       <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                           <h4 class="title">{{$menue->title}} </h4>
                                       </a>
                                       <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                           <p class="description">{{$menue->body}}</p>
                                           <br />
                                           {{$menue->price}} €
                                       </a>
                                        <div class="footer">
                                           <div class="stats">
                                               <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                                  <i class="fa fa-male"></i> {{$restaurant->name}}
                                               </a>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="stats">
                                             <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                               <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 23 Comments
                                             </a>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="stats">
                                              <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                               <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> 231 Likes
                                              </a>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>



                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                  @else
                    no article
                @endif
```